# zram zstd support in 18.04

Tags: kernel, compression, zram

On ubuntu 18.04 I would like to use zram zstd compression but it is not available as it should be available in kernel 4.15.0-36-generic? As I understand it is a kernel compilation bug as described here:

https://lkml.org/lkml/headers/2018/2/9/771

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421347/is-zstd-for-zram-actually-available-in-linux-4-15

```
cat /sys/block/zram0/comp_algorithm
lzo [lz4] lz4hc 842
```

Should I report it as a bug or someone is working on this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zstd wasn't available until 4.19 and 18.04 has 4.15.
to be able to use zstd you may want to try hwe kernels.

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

(add xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 if using a desktop)

this will install kernel of the newest released ubuntu. As of 2020/02/28, it 19.10 and 5.3 kernel series.

for more info : [LTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)